# CSS - fixed element inside relative element : positioning bug?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

I ran into a problem with a pretty weird configuration.

Working situation :

I have a basic container / content set up, with container filling up the full body, and the content with a fixed `width`, position in the middle with `margin: auto`.

Inside this content, I have a `links-container` element containing a `link` element containing my links.

This `links-container` element is `position: fixed`.
And the `link` is `position: relative` with an offset : `right: 'size'` to make links look outside of the container.

Bug :

For some pages, I need the content to slide to the right : `left: 50px`.
But for some reason, on Firefox, the links will stay close to the content, while on Chrome, they will stay at the same place.

You can see the bug [here](http://cssdesk.com/TfQqF), and the code below.

Is this a bug, or am I missing something ?

HTML :

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div class='links-container'>
      <div class='links'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: red;
  left: 50px;
}

.links-container {
  position: fixed;
}

.links {
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to give `left, top` to your `links-container` div.

Comment: @Morpheus if I do that, then my `links-container` is not positioned from the `content` element, but from the ViewPort, which I don't want.

Comment: Remove `left: 50px;` from your `.content` div

Comment: @Morpheus Well ... without the `left: 50px` we are in what I called the 'Working situation'.